# Do keys in a map also packed to storage as well?

Tags: solidity, mapping, storage-pointer

If we have this mapping

mapping(uint128 => uint256) private first;
mapping(uint128 => uint256) private second;

Do the keys of uint128 from both first and second gets stored together in one uint256 storage slot?

Answer (score 1):

The keys from the `first` and `second` mappings are not stored in the same storage slot.

```
contract Storage {
  uint8 a; // slot(0) 
  uint8 b; // slot(0)
  address c; // slot(0)

  uint256 d; // slot (1)

  mapping(uint128 => uint256) first; // slot (2)

  mapping(uint128 => uint256) second; // slot (3)
}
```

Here is a simple explanation of how the storage works:

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| slot  |  0    |  1    |   2   |   3   |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| value | a,b,c |   d   | first | second|
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

- Slot 0: a, b, and c are packed together in the same slot because they
  all fit within 32 bytes.

  **a** is 1 byte (uint8),
  **b** is 1 byte (uint8)
  **c** is 20 bytes (address)
  The total size of a, b, and c is 1 + 1 + 20 = 22 bytes
  So less than **32 bytes**.

  They are packed into the same slot and in the order they are declared.
- Slot 1: **d** use one slot because it's a uint256 it uses (32 bytes).
- Slot 2: Reference to the **first** mapping is stored. The data
  is stored in different locations calculated using keccak256.
- Slot 3: Reference to the **second** mapping is stored. The data is stored in different locations calculated using keccak256

*Based on official Solidity documentation:*

> The value corresponding to a mapping key k is located at
> keccak256(h(k) . p) where . is concatenation and h is a function that
> is applied to the key depending on its type:
>
> for value types, h pads the value to 32 bytes in the same way as when
> storing the value in memory.
>
> for strings and byte arrays, h(k) is just the unpadded data.

[Layout in storage: mapping and dynamic arrays](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.17/internals/layout_in_storage.html#mappings-and-dynamic-arrays)

Here is a simple contract I created to help to understand how to calculate the storage location for a specific `key` and `position`:

```
contract StorageLocation {
    function calculateStorageLocation(uint256 position, uint128 key) public pure returns (bytes32) {
        bytes32 paddedKey = bytes32(uint256(key));
        bytes32 paddedPosition = bytes32(position);

        return keccak256(abi.encodePacked(paddedKey, paddedPosition));
    }
}
```

We use the `calculateStorageLocation` function to find the storage location of a mapping.
For `first[3]`:

We give the function **key = 3** and **position = 2** (since `first` mapping is at slot **position 2**).
The function returns the storage location for `first[3]` as: `0x88601476d11616a71c5be67555bd1dff4b1cbf21533d2669b768b61518cfe1c3`

Similarly,

For `second[3]`:

we give the function **key = 3** and **position = 3** (since `second` mapping is at slot **position 3**).
The function returns the storage location for `second[3]` as: `0xcbc4e5fb02c3d1de23a9f1e014b4d2ee5aeaea9505df5e855c9210bf472495af`

In conclusion, first[3] and second[3] have different storage locations, so the keys of `first` and `second` mappings are stored separately.